# Показать при наведении

Tags: css3, jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте, не могу разобрать как сделать такой же эффект как [здесь](http://goo.gl/9BYJy) при наведении на товар, пробовал через css знаком **~** имея одного родителя, но понял что такой вариант мне не подойдет, либо я его не доконца реализовал.

вот что у меня получилось:

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        <h1>заголовок</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        Доп. Инфо
    </div>
</div>
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        <h1>заголовок</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        Доп. Инфо
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.items {
    width:224px;
    float:left;
}
.item {
    width:160px;
    height: 230px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid gray;
    float:left;
}
.info {
    display:none;
    float:right;
    width:60px;
    height:230px;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
.item:hover~.info,.info:hover  {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H3GmR/

Интересует сам Эффект Дополнительное пространство при наведении

---

Вроде что-то получилось http://jsfiddle.net/H3GmR/1/, если у кого есть варианты получше, или кто видит здесь костыли/косяки и прочее сообщите пожалуйста, а после закрою вопрос.

Comment: Вы принципиальный человек и вам важная причина? : ), у меня не получилось, и да я рассчитываю на помощь : )

Comment: так покажите что именно у вас не получилось - fiddle лучше всего будет. за вас что-ли всю разметку делать ?

Comment: @dogmar, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: на сайте сделано через js http://static.wildberries.ru/j/jsdata.js?2.2.59.1 в районе 354 строки функция меняющая активные элементы.

Comment: С css тут сложновато будет, это js вот тут http://static.wildberries.ru/j/jsdata.js все, это походу самописный вариант, при наведении на div меняется класс у других элементов и они становятся видимые. Вроде бы где то видел плагин под jquery, только не помню как называется, если найду дам ссылку.

Comment: Ребята, во первых прошу прощения за то что изначально начал клянчить готовый сниппет : ) вот что у меня тут получилось, http://jsfiddle.net/H3GmR/, расстояние между классами items равно ширине классу info, как от этого избавится? к примеру хочу расстояние между ними в 5px, и при этом что бы класс info был 20px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задайте position absolute скрытому блоку а родителю - relative;

```
.items {
    width:161px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
.item {        
    width:160px;
    height: 230px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
.info {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    top:0;
    left: 160px;
    display:none;
    float:right;
    width:60px;
    height:230px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/H3GmR/3/ так хочется ? (не нужно с ~ здесь заморачиваться,  просто на items делайте hover)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page https://lovehairstyles.com/insanely-cute-purple-hair-looks/ here you get some sample

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/738973)